# htaccess redirect old links to new website index and manually redirect some exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have created a new website which has a different page structure that the old one. We still want to have the contact page pointing to the contact page on the the website, the team page to the new one, and so on.

The new website is on another domain and the links are not the same - for example on the old website we had www.example.com/contact and now we have www.newexample.com/contact-us.

I would like to be able to do manual redirects for the important pages like this

```
Redirect 301 old_link new_link
```

And all the pages that are not covered in the list of manual redirects should be redirected to the new website's index.

Is this possible, or is it a better approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up this rule in your old document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Redirect to new structure
RewriteRule ^contact$ http://www.newexample.com/contact-us [L,R=301]

#Redirect all to www.newexample.com:    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You need to set this for the new site:

```
#Redirect all 404 Errors to http://www.newexample.com
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.newexample.com
```

Comment: This solution works except when the link on the website doesn't have a similar correspondant on the new website. For example, on the old website we had a blog - accessible using www.example.com/blog. On the new website there is no blog and the rule above redirects on the new website to a 404 page. Is it possible to redirect to the index in case the link is not found? Thank you

Comment: Oh, just noticed that this affects the addon domain that is setup as a subfolder in the document root... Can this also be added as an exception? Thank you!

Comment: Please clearify: What is the addon domain? Where is the subfolder and is it called setup or do you mean the setup of the subfolder?

Comment: The old domain is www.olddomain.com and it is located in /public_html. The new domain is www.newdomain.com and it is located in /www.newdomain.com. The new domain is an addon domain in cPanel.

Comment: This should do now, what you've requested...if not, let me know.

Comment: The last part (ErrorDocument) is not working as I would like. The website is Drupal based and the default .htaccess file has an entry `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`. In case of 404 it redirects to a "page not found" page generated by Drupal, instead of the homepage as I would like. But this would also have downsides, so I consider you answer as best choice! Thank you! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a Rewrite condition for each of the old urls like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(old_link) [NC]` and then put a Rewrite rule that serves all other links `RewriteRule ^(|/|/(.*))$ new_link [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Another method:
Redirect all request to a php file using .htaccess an manage via php

```
<?
$url=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$start= strrpos($url,'/')+1;

if ( strpos($url,"/old_structure/")!==false ) $newest="/new_structure";

$url=substr($url,$start);
$url=trim($url);
$domain="domain.com". $newest ."/$url";



Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://$domain" ); 
die();
?>
```